# How do I pivot this dataframe in Pandas with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that is created as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'rank': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
                   'name': ['bob', 'rick', 'bob', 'rick', 'randy', 'billy'],
                   'position': ['sanitation', 'washer', 'sanitation', 'washer', 'sanitation', 'washer']
                  })
```

This yields a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to manipulate the dataframe so that it ultimately looks like this:

[image]

Essentially, I want the duplicate rank to appear on a new line once all positions are exhausted.

When I try this:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(values='name', index='rank', columns='position')
```

I get an error "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate."

I'm not sure that would work, anyway, because I'm choosing 'rank' as index and I don't really want to index on rank. I want ranks duplicated in a new row once the list of positions is exhausted.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can assign the relative ranking with `groupby().cumcount()` then use `pivot_table`:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['rank', 'position']).cumcount()

(df.pivot_table(index=['rank','idx'], columns='position', 
               values='name', aggfunc='first')
   .reset_index('idx', drop=True)               # remove the extra `idx`
   .reset_index()                               # make rank a column
 )
```

Output:

```
position rank sanitation washer
0           1        bob   rick
1           1        bob   rick
2           2      randy  billy
```

Comment: I get KeyError: 'idx' (is this a panda version issue?)

Comment: @adhg silly me, forgot to include definition of `idx`. Thanks.

Comment: oh. Make sense now ;-) flawless solution (as always). plusOne.

Comment: That worked! Most excellent, and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here you go with cumcount create the additional key
d['key']=d.groupby(['name','position']).cumcount()
p = d.pivot_table(index=['key','name'], columns = 'type', 
values='rank',aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
p
```

Comment: Thanks Ayse, but I'm not looking for a cumulative count. I just want to pivot my dataframe by position, regardless of the value in the "rank" columns.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'rank': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
                   'name': ['bob', 'rick', 'bob', 'rick', 'randy', 'billy'],
                   'position': ['sanitation', 'washer', 'sanitation', 'washer', 'sanitation', 'washer']
                  })
df.head()
```

DataFrame.reset_index
Opposite of set_index.

DataFrame.reindex
Change to new indices or expand indices.

DataFrame.reindex_like
Change to same indices as other DataFrame.

Set the index to become the ‘rank’ column:

```
df.set_index('rank')
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you tried to do. I'm sorry I misunderstood the previous one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfN9t.png)

Comment: Kindly note that Stack Overflow isn't like a normal forum. You can edit your Answer. If looks like you have 3 separate Answers on this Question. Also note that Answers are not suppose to contain messages that refer to previous interactions, like comments. If you mean to address a comment, use another comment on the same post. Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work.

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I'm new here yet.

Comment: I recommend reading the pages in the "Help Center" about answering :) Also about asking, since even if you only want to answer, there's good information about how the site works. It takes a while to read it, but it will help you :) It's all there in the little round question mark on the top right.